# What is the simplest way to create a custom google assistant action that returns a piece of date from a web page

Tags: actions-on-google, ifttt

I want to develop a custom google assistant action that will get a web page, extract a piece of information, and read it aloud.

I'm looking for pointers for relevant sources.

If it's possible through services such as ifttt it's even better (though from what I saw the google assistant support in ifttt doesn't appear to support this scenario).

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to create an Action with the [Actions-on-Google API](https://developers.google.com/actions). The easiest way would probably be to create a Firebase Function with node.js that handles the AoG request from Google, makes the call to the web page, extracts the information you need in a form that can be read aloud, and sends that back.